# modo simplificado para definir uma propriedade a partir de um destructuring

Tags: javascript

Considerando o exemplo abaixo: Existe forma de eu simplificar?

É possível definir **_get** e **_set** diretamente como uma propriedade sem passar por **const [_get, _set]** antes?

```js
const App = class {
  constructor() {
    const [_get, _set] = FnTal()
    this._get = _get;
    this._set = _set;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Logo depois, coloquei só por curiosidade o **this** dentro do array, e que legal, deu certo!

Por um momento eu imaginei que isso pudesse ser uma facilidade do Babel, então testei no console do navegador e no Nodejs, em ambos funcionaram.

Agora sei que é possível também definir propriedades usando destructuring.

```js
const FnTal = () => [() => {}, () => []]

const App = class {
  constructor() {
    [this._get, this._set] = FnTal()
  }
}

const app = new App() // App {_get: ƒ, _set: ƒ}
```